# Redirect error with wordpress and webmatrix on local machine

Tags: wordpress, loops, redirect, webmatrix

i'm developing a theme for wordpress in webmatrix...

After few hours of normal work, i got an 302 redirect loop error in both chrome and FF...

What to do and how to fix it?

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear cache and cookies of your browser...

If that don't work, try to disable any plugins You recently have installed...